# Visual Studio JSON indenting

Tags: json, visual-studio, formatting, auto-indent

Visual Studio seems to ignore my indenting setting for JSON files. It is indenting 4 spaces, instead of my setting of 2 spaces:
[image: indenting settings]

When I format the document it looks like this:

[image: formatted document]

I am using:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit)
> Version 17.5.1

Comment: The note at the bottom may be the cause. "Adaptive formatting may override your custom tab settings...." Did you try turning it off via `Options > Text Editor > Advanced`?

Comment: I tried turning off that, but when I do "Format Document" from the context menu it still reformats with a 4 spaces indentation.

Comment: Did you try changing Indenting to none as in my answer? It worked in my testing and with it on smart it failed as in your question.

Comment: @James: Unfortunately no luck with that either.

Comment: Good call, I didn’t think of that. I could add a version of that to my question if you are inclined to award the bounty. Otherwise it will all be lost since it can’t award to the bounty creator. @NicolaAmbrosetti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that the project had an `.editorconfig` file in the root folder with

```
[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

This was overriding all the indenting options since it was "Following the project coding conventions"
[image]

UX tip to Microsoft: make it somehow visible in the Options window that some settings are overridden.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave indenting set to Smart or Block, it will match the rest of the file (or block) and ignore your choice.

To reproduce this I followed these steps:

- Set Indenting to "Smart" and Tab size/Indent Size to 8.
- Create a file and add `"sss":"x",` and `"js":"e"` with size 8.
- Change indenting to "None" and Tab/Indent to 3.
- add "," to the `"js"` line and hit return.
- It then uses size 3 as shown in the photo:
  [image: example json]